# Copy running IIS App Pool with Powershell WebAdministration

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5

I am trying to copy an existing IIS 7.5 app pool using the Powershell WebAdministration module without stopping the application.

When I copy the app pool, with an application running and loaded, I receive a NullReferenceException.

```
$pool = 'app1-0'
$newpool = 'app1-1'
cp "iis:/apppools/$pool" "iis:/apppools/$newpool" -force
```

Output:

```
Copy-Item : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I stop the pool, or start the app pool and do not load the application, the copy command succeeds.

Short of copying the properties one by one, is there a way to copy/clone a running, and loaded, app pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using appcmd instead?

**Update: try a combination of both -**

Maybe add doesn't let you both import and specify commands.  You could try something like this:

```
appcmd list appool thing1 /xml > c:\tempfile.xml
(Get-Content c:\tempfile.xml).Replace("thing1", "thing2") | Out-File c:\tempfile2.xml
appcmd add apppool /in < c:\tempfile2.xml
```

You may have to debug that script a bit :)

Comment: I can create an app pool with appcmd, but I don't see how to copy the settings from an existing pool with appcmd.

Comment: Use the appcmd list command to get just the one you want, then use /xml to export to xml.. then, at the end of the command add | appcmd add apppool /in   -    

http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2007/06/17/things-you-can-do-by-piping-appcmd-commands.aspx

The preceding is an awesome link on this concept, and very powershell-like

Comment: On my test machine, it created the apppool, but it didn't copy the settings from the other pool. Command: appcmd list APPPOOL "thing1" /xml | appcmd add APPPOOL /name:"thing2" /in

Comment: That copied the basic settings, but it didn't copy the advanced settings (periodic restart, queue length, user, etc). appcmd /text:* gives me all those settings, so I may try to convert that into the xml format.

Answer (score 4):

To export the application pool use %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list apppool "AppPoolName" /config /xml > D:\AppPoolConfig.xml

Without the /config you're missing all of the settings within the application pool and when you go to import that you're only going to create a new application pool with default application pool settings.